# Serial input parallel output shift registers with arduino

Tags: c

I need a way to rewrite the switch case part in a more efficient way.

```
int y , x ;
byte dataArray[6];

void setup () {
   pinMode(8,OUTPUT);  
   pinMode(11,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(12,OUTPUT);

   Serial.begin(9600);
   dataArray[0] = 0x3 ; //00000011
   dataArray[1] = 0x5 ; //00000101
   dataArray[2] = 0x9 ; //00001001
   dataArray[3] = 0x11; //00010001
   dataArray[4] = 0x21; //00100001
   dataArray[5] = 0x41; //01000001
}

void loop () {
   while (Serial.available()>0) {
     y = Serial.read();
     x = Serial.read();
     switch ( x ) {
     case 1:
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,dataArray[y]);
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
     break;

     case 2:
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,dataArray[y]);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(8,LOW); 
     break;

     case 3:
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,dataArray[y]);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(8,LOW); 
     break;

      case 4:
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,dataArray[y]);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(8,LOW); 
     break;

      case 5:
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,dataArray[y]);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(8,LOW); 
     break;

      case 6:
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,dataArray[y]);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(8,LOW); 
     break;

     default:
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
        digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
        delay(10);
        digitalWrite(8,LOW);
     break;
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a programming question.

Comment: @MattYoung you are right i didn't take this in mind sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unsigned char i;

digitalWrite(8,LOW);
for(i=0;i<=6;i++){
    if(x+i==6) shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,dataArray[y]);
    else shiftOut(11,12,LSBFIRST,0);
    }
digitalWrite(8,HIGH);
delay(10);
digitalWrite(8,LOW);
```

Comment: that s exactly what i need thanks alot (y)